# Does the frequency of APB1 on stm32f4 have to stay at 42 MHz?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded

I'm trying to configure the clock of my stm32 board. And I'm wondering if I always have to make the SYSCLK 168 MHz and APB1 42 MHz.

If the APB1 is not 42 MHz, I get a weird result when using uart. I assume it is determined inside the hardware and cannot be modified?

Thank you ~~
[image]

Here is the block diagram of the chip from the datasheet:
[image]

Comment: APB1 has a maximum frequency of 42MHz. The UART peripheral bases its own speed from the bus frequency. You need to set the APB1 bus speed first and then set the UART configuration afterwards. If you don't do it in this order you will get unexpected results. The APB1 bus speed can be running at almost any frequency (within reason) and your 9600 baud rate will work just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can basically make the clocks do whatever you like within their limits.

However, changing the clocks has an effect on all attached peripherals an it looks like UART 2,3,4 an 5 are connected to APB1. When you change APB1 clock you have to re-initialize the UART baudrate.

Most of the time this is done in `HAL_UART_Init()`, but if you change it afterwards you may need to deinit and init again.

*Or manually modify the BRR register.*

Comment: Thanks for answering me~
Is this the line I have to change if my APB1 != 42MHz ?
`huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;`
I guess this line change the BRR register?
So this means if I want my UART BaudRate equals to 9600, but my APB1 != 42MHz, then I should not set the `huart2.Init.BaudRate` to 9600 but instead set the value to other value according to some calculation, am I correct?

Comment: @Benasking7124 The uart init calculates your baud rate register value based on the active apb clocks. Check the code. eg: in F4: `huart->Instance->BRR = UART_BRR_SAMPLING16(HAL_RCC_GetPCLK2Freq(), huart->Init.BaudRate);`

Comment: Yes I see that! So this means the HAL library will automatically modify the BRR register for me? So if I use the Cube IDE and set the clock figuration and BaudRate in the .ioc file, I should not be worry that even if APB1 != 42MHz, the UART BaudRate will still be correct?